# How to run Celery worker as daemon with supervisord

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I'm trying to run `celery` in background with help of `supervisord` on `ubuntu` system. I've a `Flask` application located at `~/celery` directory. I followed following steps to run celery with background:

```
#install supervisor
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

Created configuration in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf`:

```
[program:celery]
directory=~/celery
command=cd ~/celery && /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/celery -A batch.celery worker -f celery.logs --loglevel=INFO
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ubuntu
```

but I'm getting `spawn` error while starting it.

My `supervisor.log`

```
2021-08-25 07:17:18,286 INFO spawned: 'celery' with pid 699710
2021-08-25 07:17:18,316 INFO exited: celery (exit status 2; not expected)
2021-08-25 07:17:19,320 INFO spawned: 'celery' with pid 699711
2021-08-25 07:17:19,350 INFO exited: celery (exit status 2; not expected)
2021-08-25 07:17:21,356 INFO spawned: 'celery' with pid 699712
2021-08-25 07:17:21,386 INFO exited: celery (exit status 2; not expected)
2021-08-25 07:17:24,392 INFO spawned: 'celery' with pid 699715
2021-08-25 07:17:24,423 INFO exited: celery (exit status 2; not expected)
2021-08-25 07:17:25,424 INFO gave up: celery entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

When I go to my `~/celery` directory and try to run:

```
celery -A batch.celery worker -f celery.logs -- loglevel=INFO
```

it runs appropriately.

Help me running celery in the background.

Answer (score 0):

It is referred to as Daemonizing Celery workers.

See documentation here

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/tutorials/daemonizing.html

$ sudo update-rc.d celeryd defaults
$ sudo service celeryd start

Comment: Here are the current docs for this: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html#daemonizing